# Kubectl - List only namespaces a user can access

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-security

Looking if the below scenario is possible or not -

Lets say user(`user1`) have access only to namespaces `default` and  `marketing`.

When we perform `kubectl get ns` it should display both namespaces.

No other namespaces should be displayed even if they exists because the `user1` does not have access to any other namespaces.

We could relate this scenario with the databases where a user can see only the databases they have access to when `show databases` is performed

Comment: What have you tried, what results are you seeing? What have you researched about how kubernetes manages permissions?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta I tried applying clusterrolebinding, it displays all the namespaces. https://github.com/avinashdesireddy/container-playground/blob/master/kubernetes/ns-reader.yaml 
Tried just the RoleBinding & Role but `kubectl get ns` is not working by I can list the pods, services, etc within the namespace.

Comment: Your request makes sense but I believe it's not possible in K8s. There are projects such as [this](https://github.com/k14s/k8s-rbac-proxy) that attempt to workaround this limitation (for the controller use case rather than users running `kubectl`).

Comment: This is not currently possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible in Kubernetes. Namespaces are the resources providing the scoping mechanism to limit visibility into other resources. There's no meta-namespace that provides scoping rules for namespaces.